# Disable panning movement on OpenCV Zoomed Window

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, pyqt, ipython

The window generated by openCV in python running in Ubuntu automatically zooms in and out using the scroll from the mouse. When it is zoomed in, the mouse pointer changes and activates a pan movement when the mouse button is pressed. Is it possible to disable this panning movement when it is zoomed in?

I'm using the opencv window as a drawing gui and I need to be able to draw instead of pan when it's zoomed in.
I'm using cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Ok @eyllanesc, I just edited and added a simple example from the OpenCV reference.

Comment: Looking for the same. I think I read once, that that is a feature of the generated window (think from qt?), so it could be that you can't disable it. I think you could build qt without that feature, then it would be disabled (in theory).

Comment: I am interested in this as well.

Comment: The comment of @Dimfred seems to be working. When running the provided code without QT installed does disable the automatic zooming and panning in the window. Not a full solution yet, as it would be nice to have this capability with QT installed as well.